Как из docker контейнера стучаться в другие сети?
Здравстуйте!
Есть некий контейнер:
version: "3"

services:

  web:
    volumes:
      - ./web:/app
    env_file:
      - ./web/.env
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'

Так же на стороннем сервре, но в той же локальной сети есть развернутый PSQL, как мне из контейнера постучаться в локальную сеть?

Обращайтесь по IP адресу. Докер по умолчанию настраивает маршрутизацию. У меня так контейнер ходит во внутренний git

PSQL тоже в контейнере? в общем docker compose?
